# Versioned XCDatamodel couldn't be open, the file .contents is missing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, core-data, xcdatamodel

I had a running Project which worked fine before push it to remote origin. Now I formatted my disk and checked out this project an I get the Error:

_MyModelDB 3.xcdatamodel: Failed to read data model Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “contents” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSFilePath=ProjectPath/Model/DBModel/MyModelDB.xcdatamodeld/._MyModelDB 3.xcdatamodel/contents, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fba9b6245d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory"}}

There is indeed no ".content" for the last versioned dbmodel. And the size of _MyModelDB 3.xcdatamodel is strangely 0KB.
Somebody an Idea ??

Comment: Sounds like your model contents were never checked in.

Comment: I took a look to my git Log and I could even see where and when  I checked the Project in. But it has 0KB

Comment: I wonder if I have to build the newest XCDatamodell a second time or if there is way where Xcode can Manage such work.

Comment: `contents` *is* the model definition.  If you don't have that, you don't have a model.

Comment: So should I remove the file MyModelDB 3.xcdatamodel and make a new one ? And what is the best Approach

Comment: You probably have to.  I would look at your model objects and reverse-engineer the model from those.  I hope you don't have to migrate anything, as you no longer have the previous model to work with.

Comment: This isn't really a Core Data question. You lost a file somehow. You can either re-create it or restore it from git or from your backups. It'd be the same for any missing file.

Comment: @HermannKlecker , Yes I could fix the problem but it is not the best solution. The Problem was indeed the empty xcdatamodel.I just removed the latest XCDatamodel with all content and created a new xcdatamodel version. I still had all the modell Classes so I just could rebuild my xcdatamodell by reverse engineering.

Comment: All right. That does not help me as I am using KVC only and don't have any model classes.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. I deleted the contents file for a data model version, and couldn't build.

The model version I deleted wasn't in the current version of the project.pbxproj file. I never pushed it up.

So I moved the entire project directory to the trash and downloaded everything fom github. 
Now the build works.